# How do I disable the full swipe on a tableview cell in iOS11

Tags: ios, uitableview, swipe, ios11, swift4

UITableViewDelegate.h

```
// Swipe actions
// These methods supersede -editActionsForRowAtIndexPath: if implemented
// return nil to get the default swipe actions
- (nullable UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);
- (nullable UISwipeActionsConfiguration *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath API_AVAILABLE(ios(11.0)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos);
```

However, I am returning nil in my trailingActions method and I still can do a full swipe to delete in my tableview.  How can I prevent the full swipe?  (I want the user to have to swipe then press the "Delete" button.

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    return nil
}
```

EDIT: I had implemented canEditRowAt and commit Editing style before the iOS 11/XCode 9/Swift 4 update.  The full swipe was enabled even BEFORE I implemented the trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using swipe actions for this case rather than edit actions? Edit actions are available since iOS 8.0+ rather than restricted to iOS 11.0+ so would provide more flexibility for devices which have not yet been upgraded to the recent iOS version. I mean this as a clarifying point, not an answer to your question.

Comment: I actually was using edit actions. I had implemented canEditRowAt and commit editing Style.  But for some reason (even before implementing trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt), the full swipe was enabled. I'm updating my question to include this

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Implement like below :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, sourceView, completionHandler) in
        print("index path of delete: \(indexPath)")
        completionHandler(true)
    }
    let swipeAction = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete])
    swipeAction.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false // This is the line which disables full swipe
    return swipeAction
}
```

This is the line which disables full swipe

```
swipeAction.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
```

And remove the other functions if you implement any like `editingStyle` and `editActionsForRowAt`.

Comment: I had some logic in the commit editingStyle function before.  Does this mean I transfer that logic into the code block of the UIContextualAction?  This seems to work, but I'm wondering if that is the best practice.

Comment: You have to transfer this logic here.

Comment: i am used "editActionsForRowAt" method to add the left swipe in tableview cell please how to all the stop the full swipe inside of this method. because i am used supper the device for below the iOS 10.0 also.? –

Comment: @ViniApp what line of code "completionHandler(true)" do in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to disable swipe actions for particular cells by following this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50597672/1072262

Instead of returning nil you can return:

```
return UISwipeActionsConfiguration.init()
```