# editActionsForRowAtIndexPath: action is called automatically when swipe

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i'm using tableview with two actions, delete and edit. when i swipe to show the action the first one returned in the array of editActionsForRowAtIndexPath: is called automatically

```
-(NSArray *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     UITableViewRowAction *deleteAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                                      {
                                         // delete ...
                                      }];

     deleteAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

     UITableViewRowAction *edit = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"  Edit  " handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath)
                              {
                                   // edit ...
                              }];
     edit.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0x2F/255.0 green:0x83/255.0 blue:0xFB/255.0 alpha:1];    

     return @[deleteAction,edit];
}
```

here the delete action is called. I want the actions to show when swipe but not to be called without tapping.

Comment: i think this is not issue. it should called once you swipe the tableviewcell. and when you click on delete , the code written in action of delete will get executed so i think this not issue.

Comment: are you saying that when you swipe from right to left your cell will be getting deleted ?

Comment: exactly and and i don't want that, i want that the user clicks on delete or edit

Comment: add a video, it is not possible that handler calls itself without selecting it

Comment: show your code for delete ? where exactly are you writing code for delete functionality ?

Comment: it's not a code or a functionality problem, if i inverse the array (@[edit,deleteAction]) , it's the edit that will be called.

Comment: are you implementing any other delegate of tableview for editing (like commitEditingStyle etc)?

Comment: no, just canEditRowAtIndexPath: witch returns YES

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to swipe table row slightly.Then it will show both the action options and actions will be called on tapping only.

Comment: is there a solution to prevent the call on swipe?

Comment: No. Because on full swipe the first action is being called by default by the swipe gesture. You can edit the sequence of actions as per your convenience. For example:-  return @[edit,deleteAction]; . So on every full swipe of cell edit action will get called instead of delete action.

Comment: You can do it with Swift. Simply implement trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt instead of editActionsForRowAtIndexPath. See this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46417015/5758986