# Segmented Control - Why wont both swipe actions disappear when checking .selectedSegmentIndex

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, uisegmentedcontrol

In my app i have swipe to delete in my segmented control and it works by showing two different tableviews, but i only want to have the swipe to delete and report to display in my case 0, and not in my case 1 (because case 1 contains other users data that the currentuser cant be able to delete or report).

I have tried using:

```
if mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete, report])
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }
```

But this only removed the report button, and not the delete button? Why is this?

This is my swipe to delete and report code :

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
  trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
   UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {

let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Delete") { (action, view, nil) in
    Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(self.currentUserID!).child(self.message[indexPath.row].messageID).setValue([])                
}

let report = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Report") { (action, view, nil) in

    let areUSureAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Are you sure you want to report?", message: "This will block this user from message you.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)  
    areUSureAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in

        Database.database().reference().child("messages").child(self.currentUserID!).child(self.message[indexPath.row].messageID).setValue([])

        let blockedPost = ["timestamp" : [".sv" : "timestamp"]]
        Database.database().reference().child("blocked").child(self.currentUserID!).child(self.message[indexPath.row].fromID).setValue(blockedPost)
    }))

    areUSureAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
        //dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }))

    self.present(areUSureAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
 }
report.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9529411793, green: 0.8918681279, blue: 0, alpha: 1)

if mySegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        return UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [delete, report])
    }
    else {
        return nil
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution here: [Delete button is automatically implemented on swipe despite not implementing trailing swipe action in tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586763/delete-button-is-automatically-implemented-on-swipe-despite-not-implementing-tra)

By implementing:

```
return UISwipeActionsConfiguration.init()
```

instead of

```
return nil
```